# Sessions in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

Hi guys I was wondering if could see what is wrong with my sessions, I have been trying to study sessions for almost 3 days but no luck.

this is log in page

```
<form action="log_php.php" method="post">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="LogInCSS.css" style="text/css">

<p><input type="text" name="inputUser" value="" placeholder="ID Number"></p>
<p><input type="password" name="inputPassword" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>

<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>         
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the checking of the inputed username and password

```
<?php
session_start();
$username=$_POST['inputUser'];
$userpass=$_POST['inputPassword'];
$SESSION['userName']=$username;

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("shuttle_service_system") 
or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("
SELECT  users.ID_No, users.User_password
FROM users
WHERE users.ID_No = '" . $username . "' 
AND users.User_password = '" . $userpass . "'   
");

$check=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($check['User_password'] == $userpass)
{   
header('location:studentUI.php');
$_SESSION['ID_No']=$row['ID_No'];
}
else header('location:ErrorLogIn.html');    
?>
```

and here is the student UI

```
<a href="logout.php">logout</a>
</br>
</br>

<?php
$user=$_SESSION['ID_No'];
$result =mysql_query("
SELECT users.First_Name as 'firstName', users.Last_Name as 'last_Name'      
FROM users
where users.ID_No = '" . $user . "';
"); while($check = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "" . $check['firstName'] . " + " . $check['lastName'] . "";
}
?>
```

It kept on displaying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Reservation system\StudentUI.php on line 94" after I have log in. So far have copied or atleast tried to understand what other sites says on how to make sessions but I am really stuck on this one.

Comment: Pleae don't use mysql_query. It's deprecated. Instead, use the `mysqli` or `PDO` extension. You can read more about it here: http://www.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: What is on line ``94``?

Comment: </html> I just shortened the code

Comment: Please hash your passwords, don't save them plain-text.

Comment: please put all the codes in here, if it's too long http://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/. you get the error unexpected end of file? did you make sure there are no whitespaces after the ending `?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many errors

```
$SESSION['userName']=$username;
```

Requires _ between $ and SESSION though I have no idea why you're setting a username session there

Usage of `mysql_*` function as others have said

No escaping of inputs not even a `mysql_real_escape_string()`

```
header('location:studentUI.php');
$_SESSION['ID_No']=$row['ID_No'];
```

You're doing a redirect before you set your ID_No session

Here's a quick rehash of your code to be a little bit more sensible its still wrong but less bads.

```
<?php
//start session may as well do it here though should be inside successful IF statement
session_start();
//connect to db should be using PDO or mysqli but this'll do for now
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("shuttle_service_system") or die(mysql_error());

//retrieve posted details
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputUser']);
$userpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputPassword']);

if (strlen($username)>0 && strlen($userpass)>0) { //very basic check to make sure something was entered it should really be validated to ensure nothing stupid like % in there!
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT users.ID_No, users.User_password FROM users
    WHERE users.ID_No = '" . $username . "' AND users.User_password = '" . $userpass . "' ");

    $check = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($check['User_password'] == $userpass) {   
        $_SESSION['UserSession'] = array('UserID' => $row['ID_No'],'UserName' => $username);  //we set an array to the session save having to create loads of sessions just use the one
        header('location:studentUI.php');  // success redirect to logged in page
    } else {
        //username not found redirect to error
        header('location:ErrorLogIn.html');    
    }
} else {
    //nothing entered so redirect to error
    header('location:ErrorLogIn.html');
}
?>
```

Now you're logged in page and check should be something like this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (count($_SESSION['UserSession'])<1 || !isset($_SESSION['UserSession'])) { 
    //we can use a simple count here because the array contains a session you should probably come up with something better  we're also doing a little check to make sure the session is set!

    //user not logged in so redirect them 
    header('location:ErrorLogIn.html');
    //this bit is important!
    die();
}
//no need for an else clause as it'll redirect and die before it hits below this if when a user isn't logged in


$UserID = $_SESSION['UserSession']['ID'];
$UserName= $_SESSION['UserSession']['UserName'];

echo "You are logged in as $UserName with the ID number $UserID";

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should really stop using all mysql_* functions as they are deprecated.
You should use PDO or mysqli for security purposes.
Here's a quick start :- http://codular.com/php-mysqli

As for the code not working, I see 2 mistakes there.

**1).** *$SESSION['userName']=$username;* should be replaced by **$_SESSION['userName']=$username;** (note the underscore)

**2).** 
Modify the student UI page as follows :-

```
<a href="logout.php">logout</a>
</br>
</br>

<?php
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['ID_No'];
$result =mysql_query("
SELECT users.First_Name as 'firstName', users.Last_Name as 'last_Name'      
FROM users
where users.ID_No = '" . $user . "';
"); while($check = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "" . $check['firstName'] . " + " . $check['lastName'] . "";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other guys said, stop using mysql_* as its deprecated and fix the $_SESSION[] error that @Ankur mentioned. More over, the error you are getting suggests you have an inconsistency in the number of curly braces in your code. Go through your whole file which throws the error and ensure that every opening curly brace has a matching closing brace.

Example:-

```
while(true)
{
    {
        //do something
        //missing brace
}
```

- missing brace could cause your error.

or:-

```
while(true)
{
    {
        //do something
    }
}
}//extra brace
```

- extra brace could cause your error.

Comment: also, bit of a long shot but if you're familiar with java there's some code here that i wrote a while ago (well, modified from another program provided by our CS tutor) which counts your braces. Check it out if you know how to compile it: http://timtalbot.co.uk/search.java

Answer (score 0):

Every page where you want to save or retrieve session variables you need to start the page with the following PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();

// The rest of your code
```

Also, make sure that there's no space or anything else before the `<?php` since that causes an error.